# Scheme of relative connected components

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon Y\to X$ be a morphism of schemes. Assume $f$ is finitely presented, flat, with geometrically reduced fibers. Then Romagny has proved that the "functor of relative geometric connected components", that sends any $X$-scheme $T$ to the set of open subschemes $U\hookrightarrow Y\times_X T$ such that $U_t$ is a connected component of $Y_t$ for every geometric point $t$ of $T$, is representable by an algebraic space Z, étale and finitely presented over $X$.

Assume now that every connected component of a fiber of $f$ is geometrically connected. Is it true that $Z$ is a scheme ? The étale map $Z\to X$ will then have split fibers (i.e., $Z_x$ is the direct sum of finitely many copies of $\mathrm{Spec}\; \kappa(x)$ for all $x\in X$), and I have the impression that the should imply that $Z$ is a scheme, but my intuition can be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Laurent Moret-Bailly has sent me an e-mail in which he describes a counter-example, so my expectation was wrong. I post his answer (in French).

---

On part d'un revêtement étale double p:Z-->X de surfaces (disons) sur un corps algébriquement clos (re-disons). On fixe un point fermé x de X, d'image réciproque {z',z"}. On prend une courbe fermée lisse irréductible C dans Z, passant par z' et z" mais telle que C-{z',z"}-->X soit une immersion. On note u l'involution de Z associée à p.
Soit $D:=C\cup u(C)=p^{-1}(p(C))$.  Alors p induit un revêtement double q:D-->p(C) qui n'a pas de section au voisinage de x, pour la raison donnée plus haut, mais dont toute fibre est formée de points rationnels.
Soit Y l'espace algébrique obtenu en «quotientant X par u, sauf le long de D». De façon précise, notant V=Z-D, Y est le quotient de Z par la relation d'équivalence R ouverte dans $Z\times_X Z$, réunion de la diagonale et de $V\times_X V$.
Alors p induit un morphisme étale f:Y-->X, qui est un isomorphisme hors de p(C) et induit le revêtement q au-dessus de p(C). En particulier ta condition sur les fibres est satisfaite.
Je dis que Y n'est pas un schéma: si W est un voisinage ouvert affine de z' (vu comme point de Y) alors W ne peut pas contenir deux points de la même fibre de f (car il est séparé). La projection W-->X est alors un monomorphisme étale, donc une immersion ouverte, donc p a une section au voisinage de x, contradiction.